# Binding to UserControl in WinRT

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I created a simple Rating user control, the problem this control won't in WinRT work when I use binding, it works fine on windows phone, This is my Control:

```
public sealed partial class RatingControl : UserControl
{
    public int Rate { get { return (int)GetValue(RateProperty); } set { SetValue(RateProperty, value); } }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Rate",
                                                                    typeof(int),
                                                                    typeof(RatingControl), null);
    public RatingControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += RatingControl_Loaded;
    }

    void RatingControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Image> Images = new List<Image>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Image img = new Image { Width = 35, Height = 35, Margin = new Thickness(3) };
            img.Source = new BitmapImage { UriSource = new System.Uri("ms-appx:Images/Stars/notFilled.png") };
            Images.Add(img);
            sp.Children.Add(img);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < Rate; i++)
            Images[i].Source = new BitmapImage { UriSource = new System.Uri("ms-appx:Images/Stars/Filled.png") };
    }
}
```

When I hardcode the value, it works fine:

```
<local:RatingControl Rate="3" />
```

but when I use Binding, it just shows zero stars. I checked the value of Rate, it is always zero.

```
<local:RatingControl Rate="{Binding Decor, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

UPDATE: I just found out that the binding happens before I get the value of the Rate, so its zero all the time. How can I fix that? I need the binding to happens after I get the value. Also I thought the Binding happens everytime I change the Rate value.

SOLUTION: I Didnt implement the DependencyObject right, I should've done this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty RateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Rate",
                                                                    typeof(int),
                                                                    typeof(RatingControl), new PropertyMetadata(0, new PropertyChangedCallback(BindRateControl)));
```

Comment: What's your DataContext? I think this could be caused by a binding error. You can often track them in the Output/Debug window (Ctrl+W,O). Maybe the type of Decor is not int.

Comment: I did check, it gives numbers. and same code works fine on wp7.

Comment: Can you share a test project? The binding should occur in the InitializeComponent call or maybe soon after. The Loaded event is likely to happen later. Where do you change the Rate value in your control?

Comment: could you share your solution? I've got a similar problem...

Comment: I did share the solution, you will find it by the end of my question. If that doesnt help i'll share the whole code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION: I Didnt implement the DependencyObject right, I should've done this (adding a callback method):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty RateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Rate",
                                                                typeof(int),
                                                                typeof(RatingControl), 
                                                                new PropertyMetadata(0, new PropertyChangedCallback(BindRateControl)));
```

Answer (score 0):

has you try adding the UserControl from code-behind. this help you to ensure that the UserControl is triggered after getting the value.